# Determining if item in list is last item in list

Tags: python

I have a function `printListAsSentence(l)` where `l` should be a `list`. This function should print the items in a list separated by a comma, unless it is the last item in the list, then it should end with a period. I thought I could use `l[-1]`, but that is not working. Here is my attempt:

```
def printListAsSentence(l):
    for item in l:
        if item == l[-1]: #This compares the value of the strings. Only will work if there is no duplicate values.
            print(item + ".", end="")
        else:
            print(item + ",", end="")
```

An example:

```
names = ['rob', 'jack', 'rob']
printListAsSentence(names)
```

Would output:

```
"rob.jack,rob."
```

Comment: If this isn't the output you want, what *do* you want?  If it is, why are you here?

Comment: How about ```','.join(l)+'.'```?

Comment: `','.join(l)+'.'`

Comment: Read the comment in the code you provided. That explains the behavior

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` to put a `,` between each string and then just concatenate the last dot:

```
print(",".join(l) + ".")
```

If you did want to loop manually, one way would be to use `enumerate`:

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if index == len(l)-1:
        # this is the last item
    else:
        # it's not the last item
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use `join`:

```
names=['rob', 'jack', 'rob']
','.join(names) + '.'
# 'rob,jack,rob.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt doesn't work when you have duplicates of the last item in the list, since you're checking the item's value, not its actual place in the list. You could use `enumerate()` to get the item's index as well as its value.

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    if index = len(l)-1:
        print(item + ".", end="")
    else:
        print(item + ",", end="")
```

But the other suggestions to use `join` are the more pythonic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could print all the items except the last one using a for loop and then handle the last one outside of the loop:

```
for item in l[:-1]:
    print(item, end=",")
print(l[-1]+".")
```